# Trazer combo selecionada preenchida manualmente

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou com dificuldade de criar uma combo de "Habilitado" e "Desabilitado" passando o valor do banco para trazê-la preenchida. No meu **controller**, criei o seguinte código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na minha **View**, seguinte código:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado é que, com o código rodando, sempre vai aparecer "Habilitado" lá na combo.

Comment: O `gestor.Status` é um bool ou um int?

Comment: É um bool @FilipeOliveira

Answer (score 1):

Como o `gestor.Status` é um bool, ou você muda o `Value` para bool:

```
lista.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Habilitado", Value = "True" });
lista.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Desabilitado", Value = "False" });
```

Ou converte o seu `gestor.Status` para inteiro:

```
ViewBag.Status = new SelectList(lista, "Value", "Text", Convert.ToInt32(gestor.Status));
```

Comment: Mudei o Value para "True" e "False". Na hora de salvar, funciona perfeitamente, passando o valor correto, conforme o selecionado. Porém, na hora de editar, ele não traz o selecionado, conforme o banco... Tem alguma ideia do que pode ser? Atualmente estou passando a ViewBag assim:  `ViewBag.Status = new SelectList(lista.AsEnumerable(), "Value", "Text", gestor.Status);`

Comment: @IgorMacedo, o `gestor.Status` está vindo False mesmo? Por alto, não consigo imaginar qual seja o problema, se o boleano estiver correto, ele irá exibir correto também

Comment: @FilipeOliveria, debuguei e passa pelo controller com o valor certo. Porém, quando vou editar, passa pelo controller com valor certo, porém na hora de visualizar, ele não marca a que está selecionada, como se estivesse sem o 4º parâmetro: `gestor.Status`

Comment: @IgorMacedo, a lista está sendo preenchida da mesma forma? O value está correto?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira, está sim. Na hora de inserir um novo registro, ele insere conforme selecionei no combo. Só na hora de editar que ele não traz o selecionado :/

Comment: @IgorMacedo, o ideal seria ver como está o código. Poderia editar sua pergunta mostrando um exemplo de como está as actions de inserir e editar e suas respectivas views? E coloca em texto mesmo, não em imagem.